# Retrieve Custom HTTP Post Response Status Descriptions within BizTalk

Tags: http, post, biztalk

How can I retrieve a custom HTTP ResponseStatusDescription resulting from a POST through a HTTP Send Adapter for both successful (ACKs / StatusCode == 200) and unsuccessful (NACKs / StatusCode != 200) posting

i.e. response from Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 ResponseStatusDescription
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 10:19:06 GMT

2c
This is the response body, statuscode: '200'
0
```

Example invalid response:

```
HTTP/1.1 408 Custom Status Description
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 14:42:37 GMT

2c
This is the response body, statuscode: '408'
0
```

If it helps, I am testing against a simple asp.net web project with the Page_Load overridden as below:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Response.SuppressContent = false;
        //Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        Response.StatusDescription = "ResponseStatusDescription";
        string Resp = string.Format("This is the response body, statuscode: '{0}'", Response.StatusCode);
        Response.Write(Resp);
        Response.Flush();

    }
```

Comment: Can you please post a response for !=200 as well? I'll send you the flat file schema for that.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 408 Custom Status Description
    Cache-Control: private
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 14:42:37 GMT

2c
This is the response body, statuscode: '408'
0

Answer (score 0):

Using the schema below, create a Receive Pipeline, with a flat file disassembler component and in the properties, use the schema below. Now use this custom receive pipeline in the receive response part of your HTTP port.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://httpresponse.httpresponse" targetNamespace="http://httpresponse.httpresponse" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="HTTPResponse" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="HTTPResponse">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="Line1" type="xs:string">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Line2">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="'" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Text" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HTTPResponseCode" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Line3" type="xs:string">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I created the pipeline as suggested and added the schema to "Document schema" property, however I received a pipeline execution error (Reason: Unexpected data found while looking for:
'\r\n'
The current definition being parsed is HTTPResponse. The stream offset where the error occured is 0. The line number where the error occured is 1. The column where the error occured is 0.) for a 200 response and for a 400 response a system exception was thrown of type Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.XlangSoapException with the Error Description: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: For the success scenario, the End Of Line ( EOL character) needs to be changed to whatever you are receiving i.e. on CR or LF. What I have defined is CRLF. You need to change this in the schema at **child_delimiter="0xD 0xA"**. For the failure scenario, its a bit more complex. As the HTTP header code is 400, Biztalk assumes its a failure straightaway. So, I guess it doesn't even bother to process the response body.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. Would writing a custom adapter be the valid approach to handle both success and failed status codes?

Comment: Also, I guess you need to handle the SOAP exception within your orchestration. A good post on how to handle SOAP exceptions is [here](http://blogs.digitaldeposit.net/saravana/post/2007/05/16/Orchestration-Handle-SOAP-Exception-and-deal-with-Suspended-(resumable)-messages.aspx)

Comment: Also noticed, in your ASP.net web project, you are not sending 3 lines i.e. 2c on line 1, description on line 2 and '0' on line 3. If you can format your response into 3 lines with '\r\n' as new line characters, the success scenario should work.

Comment: I am not sure where the additional characters are coming from...these were displayed in Fiddler and I assumed they were some type of delimiter.

Comment: In that case, delete the Line1 and Line3 nodes in the schema and you should be fine.